# At the end of the season, what decides tiebreakers in the NHL?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl, tie-breaker

If at the end of an NHL seasons if 2 teams tie in points, who gets the higher seed? What break ties? And if that thing is tied too, what further breaks the tie? And what would a perfect tie be?

Comment: Any research effort at all?

Comment: See also: [What is tie-breaking procedure in NHL (regular season)?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4471)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [very easy to find page on ESPN](http://www.espn.com/nhl/news/story?page=nhl/tiebreakers):

> 1. The fewer number of games played (i.e., superior points percentage).
> 2. The greater number of games won, excluding games won in the Shootout. [...]
> 3. The greater number of points earned in games between the tied clubs. [...]
> 4. The greater differential between goals for and against for the entire regular season.

What happens if two (or more!) teams are still tied after all four tiebreakers is possibly an open question.